# Yoast Force Rewrite Crashed Site

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I just applied force rewrite in [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin and now cannot access my site at all am getting a Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error. message in Chrome and "Content Encoding Error The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression." in Firefox

Please HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the plugin dir through FTP and it'll deactivate. It's probably clashing with another plugin...

Comment: Thanks. I found it was clashing with gzip - I removed the line of gzip at the top of the header.php, the site worked, i then turned off the force rewrite, and then reinserted the line of code and all works ok - very strange but relief.